# How do I recover a blender file that looks like a new file when I open it?

Tags: blend-files

I have been working on a file for a while and I know I saved it before I closed it, but when I opened it again it says I´ve opened it but it looks like a new file. With the cube and the light etc. I´ve tried to open it in several different ways but it always just looks like a new file. Completely gone. What do I do?

Comment: in the file menu use recover last autosave or recover last session

Comment: If you see the old objects in the outliner, you could try to append them to a (really) new file. The broken file may be damaged beyond repair, but the new one will get all objects from the other and you can continue your work on it.

Comment: I tried recovering the autosave, its still just the cube and the lamp. And there are none of my objects in the outliner. I dont get what happened